# How do you remove the deploymentConfig, image streams, etc using Openshift OC?

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, kubernetes, openshift-origin

After creating a new app using `oc new-app location/nameofapp`, many things are created: a deploymentConfig, an imagestream, a service, etc. I know you can run `oc delete <label>`. I would like to know how to delete all of these given the label.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When using `oc new-app`, it would normally add a label on each resource created call `app` with value being the name given to the application. That name would be based on the name of the git repository, or could have been supplied using the `--name` option. Knowing that to delete everything you can then run:

```
oc delete all --selector app=appname
```

Before you delete anything you should be able to check what would matche by running:

```
oc get all --selector app=appname
```

Note that if creating from a template, rather than a repository, how things are labelled can depend on what the template itself sets up, so the instructions above may not apply.

Comment: Also, do you mind voting this question up? The online OpenShift documentation doesn't do a great job of explaining this. I'm sure this would help other out.

Comment: also, I believe running 'oc scale dc <app-name> --replicas=0' is prudent prior to deleting all of the resources. wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Personally I never bother to scale down to 0 replicas first, but then these are throw away applications for me. So the platform itself doesn't care if you don't stop things first, it will stop containers in the same way that would occur if scaled down. That is, signal sent to container to stop it, allowing the application to shutdown in an orderly manner if need be.

Comment: Ahhh. I know when shutting things down manually in the web app, funky things occur if you delete config files or instances before scaling down the app itself. For example, I've deleted some instances and then the replication controller would simply create another instance.

Comment: Possibly, it probably doesn't apply any sort of algorithm to determine a sensible order to delete things in.